# atomic concentration by lattice constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, semiconductor-physics

How to determind the atomic concentration by lattice constant?

As a example

> Crystalline germanium has the diamond lattice structure with a lattice constant $5.66*10^{-10}$ at 300K how to find the atomic concentration?

Comment: Calculate the volume of a unit cell, see how many unit cells fit into a cm³. Did you try anything on your own before asking here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You also need to know what the diamond lattice resembles.

Comment: Make sure you understand the concepts *unit cell*, *primitive cell* and *Bravais lattice*.  I think you don't, and the point of the problem is to make sure that you do.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic concentration is the number of atoms that can fit into a given volume and therefore has the dimension of inverse volume.

To calculate the atomic concentration one needs to know two things: the lattice constant to calculate the volume of the unit cell and the number of atoms that can fit into the lattice. The number of atoms that can fit into a lattice is a known property for different crystal structures, such as bcc, fcc, hcp, etc.

For your example question, both the crystal structure (diamond) and the lattice constant is known and atomic concentration can easily be calculated.

Alternatively one can calculate the atomic concentration by using density, atomic mass and Avogadro's number.